# html5 video download percentage of video before starting to play

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I have this video tag:

```
 <video autoplay id="Video2">
                <source src="http://myurl/firstanimation01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://myurl/firstanimation01.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
```

What I would like to achieve is with jQuery or some other approach download enough content from the video before it starts to load. On some slow connections we get complaints from customers that the video is lagging, and there are often moments when the customers get stuck because of that.

What approach is recommended for these issues? Should I download whole video locally, set the path dynamically in jQuery and once downloaded start the video? 
Some other approach for progressive loading?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the [preload](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) HTML5 attribute setting.

```
  <video preload = auto>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mitchell's suggestion, but I would suggest trying `preload="metadata"` first.
I would also suggest providing a link for the users to download the video themselves if they wish to.